# How to roll start and end date in a month?

Tags: python, python-dateutil

I want to write a function that looks ahead 1 year but can accept a certain month as the date to start counting from.

For example, if the start time is `1/1/2011`, then the end time is `1/1/2012`. The new start time would be `1/2/2011` and new end time would be `1/2/2012`. The start and end times should advance like that.

Here is my attempt:

```
    import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import date

def Count(StartDate, EndDate,count):
     #while StartDate < FinalDate:
     count = 1
     print (StartDate, EndDate)

StartDate = date(2011,01,01)
FinalDate = date (2014,01,01)
EndDate = StartDate + relativedelta(years=+1)
count = 1


a = Count(StartDate, EndDate,count)
print a
```

print something like

```
(datetime.date(2011, 2, 1), datetime.date(2012, 2, 1))
None
(datetime.date(2011, 3, 1), datetime.date(2012, 3, 1))
None
(datetime.date(2011, 4, 1), datetime.date(2012, 4, 1))
None
(datetime.date(2011, 5, 1), datetime.date(2012, 5, 1))
None
(datetime.date(2011, 6, 1), datetime.date(2012, 6, 1))
None
```

Comment: Have you looked at the datetime function... or googled anything?

Comment: Please show your work. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: This is my first time asking here so I am trying to figure out a way to post my code.

Comment: You can [edit] your question, and then copy and paste the code into it. Afterwards, select what was just pasted and use the `{}` button to indicate that it should be displayed as code.

Comment: Thank you, I just edited my post.

Comment: I would like the code to print something once every month until the final date is met.

Comment: @S.A So you want to print the start date, every month up until a year, and then the end date?

Comment: yes, print out start date and end date until the final date is met. Something like 2011-1-1_ 2012-1-1, 2011-2-1_2012-2-1

Comment: Your question is still unclear. Please [edit] it again, and show the output you would like printed (and format it the same way you did the code, even though technically it isn't code).

Comment: @martineau: I just edited the code. If you please run this code, it runs and print only one set of start and end date. But I want it to code it in a way that until the final date is met, keep printing start and end date. thank you

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the non-standard `dateutil` module installed. I wanted you to show what you expected to printed because doing so would likely fill in some missing details about what you're wanting to do.

Comment: print something like this                                               (datetime.date(2011, 2, 1), datetime.date(2012, 2, 1) None)
(datetime.date(2011, 3, 1), datetime.date(2012, 3, 1) None)
(datetime.date(2011, 4, 1), datetime.date(2012, 4, 1) None)
(datetime.date(2011, 5, 1), datetime.date(2012, 5, 1) None)
(datetime.date(2011, 6, 1), datetime.date(2012, 6, 1) None)

Comment: @S.A You need to put that in the question body, and format it the same way you did the code.

Comment: @ChristianDean: I just did.

Answer (score 1):

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

new_date = old_date + relativedelta(years=1)

#you can use this for getting the 1 year later date 
#or use

#adding to date
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
new_date = datetime.today()
new_date = new_date + timedelta(months=1)
new_date = new_date + timedelta(years=1)
```

Comment: if you understood that was a comment

Comment: I didn't downvote your post. There's no way to know who downvoted your post unless someone comments. Votes on Stack Overflow are anonymous. I can reason why someone might have though. You're giving a code only answer to a low quality question. That only serves to encourage more low quality questions.

Comment: but i was just trying to help out

Comment: @abhishek `why did you downvote` correct the problems from your answer then ask why did they downvote. Not everyone will understand that your // was a comment

Comment: actually i'm new to it... so i was little confused but corrected it.

Comment: I know you were, but like I said above, you answering will only encourage more questions that are low quality. We generally try to refrain from answering low quality questions. I usually don't downvote an answer unless it's flat out wrong, but some people do.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import date

def Count(StartDate, EndDate,count):
     #while StartDate < FinalDate:
     count = 1
     print (StartDate, EndDate)

    StartDate = date(2011,01,01)
    FinalDate = date (2014,01,01)
    EndDate = StartDate + relativedelta(years=+1)
    count = 1

    while StartDate < FinalDate:
         StartDate = StartDate + relativedelta(months=+1)
         EndDate = StartDate + relativedelta(years=+1)
         a = Count(StartDate, EndDate,count)
         print a
```

Comment: I think I got the answer I was looking for. Thank you guys for your attempt to help me. I think I could not clearly mention what I was looking for.